# Unable to install tensorflow_federated

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab to try federated learning with TensorFlow. I met some issues when installing tensorflow_federated. I undestand that tensorflow tff requires the python version to be 3.9 or higher, but the python current vesion is 3.10.12, the version of sys is also the same, so how do I solve this?

Code:
`!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated`

Error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
arviz 0.15.1 requires scipy>=1.8.0, but you have scipy 1.7.3 which is incompatible.
chex 0.1.7 requires jax>=0.4.6, but you have jax 0.3.15 which is incompatible.
orbax-checkpoint 0.2.6 requires jax>=0.4.9, but you have jax 0.3.15 which is incompatible.
pymc 5.1.2 requires cachetools>=4.2.1, but you have cachetools 3.1.1 which is incompatible.
```

I also tried downloading tensorflow 0.20.0 and 0.55.0 as some people have suggested but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below steps I was able to get to run. Please note that future dependencies can easily cause this workaround to break.

1. Change the runtime to a GPU session within Google Colab.
2. Install the below package dependencies manually

```
!pip install jax==0.4.10
!pip install cachetools==4.2.1
!pip install dp_accounting
!pip install tensorflow_privacy
!pip install tensorflow_compression
!pip install tensorflow_model_optimization
!pip install pyfarmhash
!pip install google-vizier
```

3. Restart the runtime.
4. Install tensorflow_federated without any dependencies.

`!pip install --no-deps tensorflow-federated`

5. Test to make sure tensorflow_federated works.

```
import tensorflow_federated as tff
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')()
```

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue/error found installing `TF Federated` in `Google Colab` using `Python 3.10`. Could you please try again installing the `TF Federated` in `Colab` and check if the issue still persists?

```
!pip install tensorflow-federated # (restart the kernel)

import tensorflow_federated as tfds
tfds.__version__
```

Output:

```
'0.61.0'
```

Please see this screenshot below:(It's installing the latest TF Federated version 0.61.0)

[image]

Comment: I no longer have this issue anymore for the latest tensorflow federated version. If I'm not mistaken, the version with the issue was 0.59.0. Thanks for helping.